# How can I convert big python project to exe file?

Tags: python

I have a Python Qt GUI which is using these modules:
"Numpy, scipy, matplotlib-base, netcdf4, cartopy, xarray, pytest, gdal, cycler, dateutil, kiwisolver, pillow, pyparsing, tk, PyQt5, pycairo, tornado, proj4, geos"

Project has many components and plugins. It is working correctly through python but I want to convert it to 'one file exe' and easily run in other systems. I tried pyinstaller, when i run the exe file, it is running but no windows open. Do you have any suggestions for converting projects to exe correctly with modules or how can I add modules to following setup.py?

Edit: Tried cx-freeze, successfully creating the exe file but it closes as soon as it opens. I can run the file in terminal without any problem.

This is my setup.py:

```
def configuration(parent_package='', top_path=None):
 from numpy.distutils.misc_util import Configuration
 config = Configuration('rd1project', parent_package, top_path)
 config.add_subpackage('core')
 config.add_subpackage('components')
 config.add_subpackage('plugins')
 config.add_subpackage('scripts')
 config.add_subpackage('components.corrections')
 config.add_subpackage('icons')
 config.add_data_dir('icons')

return config

if __name__ == '__main__':
   from numpy.distutils.core import setup
   setup(**configuration(top_path='').todict())
```

This is my **main**.py:

```
import sys
import os

path = os.path.dirname(sys.modules[__name__].__file__)
path = os.path.join(path, '..')
sys.path.insert(0, path)

import artview
try:
    from version import profiling
except:
    profiling = False


def main(argv):
    if profiling:
        import cProfile, pstats
        pr = cProfile.Profile()
        pr.enable()

    script, DirIn, filename, field = artview.parser.parse(argv)

    if script:
        artview.scripts.scripts[script](DirIn, filename, field)
    else:
        artview.run(DirIn, filename, field)

    if profiling:
        pr.disable()
        stream = open('profile.txt', 'w')
        ps = pstats.Stats(pr, stream=stream).sort_stats('cumulative')
        ps.print_stats('artview')
        stream.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

I tried to pyinstaller, exe file is running but no windows opening after a while fatal error detected windows shows up "Failed to execute script **main**"

pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole **main**.py

Output:

```
1176 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.2
1176 INFO: Python: 3.8.5 (conda)
1177 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
1178 INFO: wrote C:\Users\PC\pyinstaller\artview\__main__.spec
1182 INFO: UPX is not available.
1197 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\PC\\pyinstaller', 'C:\\Users\\PC\\pyinstaller\\artview']
1221 INFO: checking Analysis
1221 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
1222 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
1227 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
1234 WARNING: Several hooks defined for module 'win32ctypes.core'. Please take care they do not conflict.
1238 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
3545 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-distutils.py'.
3546 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib'
6501 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
6643 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
6656 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\python.exe
6746 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\PC\pyinstaller\artview\__main__.py
10909 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook setuptools.extern.six.moves from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-setuptools.extern.six.moves.py'.
11420 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook site from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-site.py'.
11421 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
14977 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook six.moves from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-six.moves.py'.
20666 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook urllib3.packages.six.moves from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-urllib3.packages.six.moves.py'.
C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyart\core\grid.py:318: SyntaxWarning: "is not" with a literal. Did you mean "!="?
  if meta is not 'data':
45679 INFO: Processing module hooks...
45680 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-certifi.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
45685 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-cryptography.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
45917 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-IPython.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
46426 INFO: Excluding import of tkinter from module IPython.lib.clipboard
46432 INFO: Excluding import of PyQt5.QtWidgets from module IPython.external.qt_loaders
46433 INFO: Excluding import of PyQt5.QtCore from module IPython.external.qt_loaders
46433 INFO: Excluding import of PyQt5.QtSvg from module IPython.external.qt_loaders
46433 INFO: Excluding import of PyQt5.QtGui from module IPython.external.qt_loaders
46434 INFO: Excluding import of PyQt5 from module IPython.external.qt_loaders
46440 INFO: Excluding import of matplotlib.pyplot from module IPython.core.pylabtools
46440 INFO: Excluding import of matplotlib._pylab_helpers from module IPython.core.pylabtools
46440 INFO: Excluding import of matplotlib.figure from module IPython.core.pylabtools
46443 INFO: Excluding import of matplotlib.backend_bases from module IPython.core.pylabtools
46444 INFO: Excluding import of matplotlib from module IPython.core.pylabtools
46450 INFO: Excluding import of PySide from module IPython.external.qt_loaders
46456 INFO: Excluding import of PyQt4 from module IPython.external.qt_loaders
46462 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-jedi.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
47510 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-jinja2.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
47588 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-jsonschema.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
47605 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-nbconvert.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
47702 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-nbformat.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
47753 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-netCDF4.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
47776 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-notebook.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
50231 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-osgeo.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
50237 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pycparser.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
50238 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pytest.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
50944 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-shapely.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
50945 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-zmq.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
51160 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-difflib.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
51168 INFO: Excluding import of doctest from module difflib
51168 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
51170 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.util.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
51176 INFO: Excluding import of lib2to3.refactor from module distutils.util
51176 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
51247 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
51253 INFO: Excluding import of doctest from module heapq
51253 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-importlib_metadata.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
51255 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lib2to3.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
51288 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-matplotlib.backends.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
51835 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK": ignored
    Gtk* backend requires pygtk to be installed.
52213 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTKAgg": ignored
    Gtk* backend requires pygtk to be installed.
52490 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTKCairo": ignored
    No module named 'gtk'
52865 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK3Agg": ignored
    The Gtk3 backend requires PyGObject or pgi
53146 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK3Cairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that cairocffi or pycairo is installed
53528 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "MacOSX": ignored
    cannot import name '_macosx' from 'matplotlib.backends' (C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\__init__.py)
54360 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "nbAgg": added
54807 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt4Agg": added
55075 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt4Cairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that cairocffi or pycairo is installed
55500 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt5Agg": added
55775 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt5Cairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that cairocffi or pycairo is installed
56173 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "TkAgg": added
56464 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "TkCairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that cairocffi or pycairo is installed
56927 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WebAgg": added
57299 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WX": ignored
    Matplotlib backend_wx and backend_wxagg require wxPython>=2.9
57565 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WXAgg": ignored
    No module named 'wx'
57833 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WXCairo": ignored
    No module named 'wx'
58209 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "agg": added
58481 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "cairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that cairocffi or pycairo is installed
58755 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "gdk": ignored
    No module named 'gobject'
59136 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "pdf": added
59582 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "pgf": added
59958 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "ps": added
60338 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "svg": added
60714 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "template": added
61019 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-matplotlib.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
61304 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-multiprocessing.util.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
61309 INFO: Excluding import of test from module multiprocessing.util
61310 INFO: Excluding import of test.support from module multiprocessing.util
61310 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-numpy.core.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
61390 INFO: MKL libraries found when importing numpy. Adding MKL to binaries
61392 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-numpy.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
61393 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-numpy._pytesttester.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
61400 INFO: Excluding import of pytest from module numpy._pytesttester
61400 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-packaging.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
61402 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pandas.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
62026 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
62032 INFO: Excluding import of argparse from module pickle
62032 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pkg_resources.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
62703 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook win32com from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-win32com.py'.
62933 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.py2_warn" not found!
62949 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.markers" not found!
62955 INFO: Excluding import of __main__ from module pkg_resources
62956 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pygments.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
64371 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
64482 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtCore.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
64551 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtGui.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
64693 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtSvg.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
65077 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
65326 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PySide2.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
66219 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PySide2.QtCore.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
66314 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PySide2.QtGui.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
66440 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PySide2.QtNetwork.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
66754 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PySide2.QtPrintSupport.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
67020 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PySide2.QtSvg.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
67500 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PySide2.QtWidgets.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
67758 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pytz.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
67909 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.io.matlab.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
67910 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.linalg.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
67911 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
67917 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.sparse.csgraph.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
67920 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.spatial.transform.rotation.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
67989 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.special._ellip_harm_2.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
67989 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.special._ufuncs.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
67991 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.stats._stats.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
67994 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-setuptools.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
68588 INFO: Excluding import of setuptools.py27compat from module setuptools.command.easy_install
68588 INFO: Excluding import of setuptools.py27compat from module setuptools.package_index
68589 INFO: Excluding import of setuptools.py27compat from module setuptools.depends
68593 INFO: Excluding import of setuptools.py33compat from module setuptools.package_index
68594 INFO: Excluding import of setuptools.py33compat from module setuptools.depends
68596 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sqlite3.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
68670 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sysconfig.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
68672 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-wcwidth.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
68676 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.dom.domreg.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
68677 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
68677 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
68678 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-_tkinter.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
68808 INFO: checking Tree
68808 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-00.toc is non existent
68812 INFO: Building Tree Tree-00.toc
68874 INFO: checking Tree
68874 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-01.toc is non existent
68875 INFO: Building Tree Tree-01.toc
68963 INFO: checking Tree
68963 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-02.toc is non existent
68964 INFO: Building Tree Tree-02.toc
68979 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pythoncom.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
69341 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pywintypes.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
69702 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-win32com.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
70253 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-setuptools.msvc.py' from 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
70261 INFO: Excluding import of numpy from module setuptools.msvc
70392 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
70638 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
70656 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
70659 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pyqt5.py'
70660 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pkgres.py'
70661 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_win32api.py'
70662 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_win32comgenpy.py'
70663 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
70664 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pyside2.py'
70665 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_traitlets.py'
70667 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_certifi.py'
70668 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_osgeo.py'
70669 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_mplconfig.py'
70712 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
70741 WARNING: lib not found: msmpi.dll dependency of C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_msmpi_ilp64.dll
71092 WARNING: lib not found: mpich2mpi.dll dependency of C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_mpich2_lp64.dll
71100 WARNING: lib not found: msmpi.dll dependency of C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_msmpi_lp64.dll
71336 WARNING: lib not found: impi.dll dependency of C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_intelmpi_ilp64.dll
71579 WARNING: lib not found: mpich2mpi.dll dependency of C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_mpich2_ilp64.dll
71941 WARNING: lib not found: pgf90.dll dependency of C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_pgi_thread.dll
71944 WARNING: lib not found: pgc14.dll dependency of C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_pgi_thread.dll
71951 WARNING: lib not found: pgf90rtl.dll dependency of C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_pgi_thread.dll
72025 WARNING: lib not found: impi.dll dependency of C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_intelmpi_lp64.dll
73253 WARNING: lib not found: shiboken2.abi3.dll dependency of C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PySide2\QtWidgets.pyd
73272 WARNING: lib not found: shiboken2.abi3.dll dependency of C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PySide2\QtGui.pyd
73293 WARNING: lib not found: shiboken2.abi3.dll dependency of C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PySide2\QtCore.pyd
73311 WARNING: lib not found: shiboken2.abi3.dll dependency of C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PySide2\QtPrintSupport.pyd
73332 WARNING: lib not found: shiboken2.abi3.dll dependency of C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PySide2\QtSvg.pyd
73351 WARNING: lib not found: shiboken2.abi3.dll dependency of C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PySide2\QtNetwork.pyd
75431 WARNING: lib not found: shiboken2.abi3.dll dependency of C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PySide2\pyside2.abi3.dll
76384 INFO: Looking for eggs
76384 INFO: Using Python library C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\python38.dll
76385 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
76410 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\PC\pyinstaller\artview\build\__main__\warn-__main__.txt
76806 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\PC\pyinstaller\artview\build\__main__\xref-__main__.html
76995 INFO: checking PYZ
76995 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
76996 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\PC\pyinstaller\artview\build\__main__\PYZ-00.pyz
80980 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\PC\pyinstaller\artview\build\__main__\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
81057 INFO: checking PKG
81058 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
81058 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
193762 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
193892 INFO: Bootloader C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\runw.exe
193893 INFO: checking EXE
193893 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
193894 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
193899 INFO: Copying icons from ['C:\\Users\\PC\\pyinstaller\\artview\\icons\\radar-icon.ico']
193977 INFO: Writing RT_GROUP_ICON 0 resource with 48 bytes
193977 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 1 resource with 1128 bytes
193978 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 2 resource with 4264 bytes
193982 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 3 resource with 9640 bytes
193985 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\PC\pyinstaller\artview\build\__main__\runw.exe.tamvchun
194030 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 1 language 0
194033 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\PC\pyinstaller\artview\dist\__main__.exe
194297 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

Comment: Did you do any searching for solutions? There are many questions on here about PyInstaller issues with the exe, some with answers ;-) Also check the PyInstaller documentation, there’s a section ‘when things go wrong’. I’m sure you can find it.

Comment: Yes, I've been looking for a solution for a while.

Comment: You need to find out more about the error that occurs at runtime - refer to the PyInstaller documentation for guidance.

Comment: @malicelik Did you ever find a suitable solution? I am struggling with a similar issue, and I find few good examples for my project

Answer (score 1):

cx_Freeze is preferred for converting big python projects(containing various modules and library).

I would prefer doing project in virtual environment, as it will be easy to manage required libraries.
In virtual environment, do...

```
pip install cx_Freeze
```

Create a setup.py file and place it where your main_file.py is.
In setup.py, paste the following code

```html
from cx_Freeze import setup,Executable
setup(
    name="your_project_name",
    version=0.1,
    description="project_description",
    executables=[Executable("your_main_file.py",base="Win32GUI")],
)
```

Now cd into your folder, where both setup.py and main.py is there.
Run:

```
python setup.py build
```

A new folder will be created named "build", Inside of that folder, you will find your .exe file.

Comment: DO PROJECT IN VIRTUAL ENVIRONMENT, TO RUN cx_Freeze PROPERLY, WITH ALL REQUIRED LIBRARAY ALREADY INSTALLED IN VIRTUAL ENV.